# How to correctly place PHP echo inside html span tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've got the following function:

```
<?php
function my_custom_address ( $formats ) {
     $formats = array( 
        'default' => '<span class="my-address-country"></span>
                      <span class="my-address-city"></span>'
     ); 
     return $formats; 
} 
add_filter( 'default_address_formats', 'my_custom_address', 15 ) ;
?>
```

And I'm trying to place the following output inside the span tags:

```
$listing_address_country = get_my_field( 'address_country' );
echo $listing_address_country; 

$listing_address_city = get_my_field( 'address_city' );
echo $listing_address_city;
```

The closest I came up with the following:

```
function my_custom_address ( $formats ) {

     $listing_address_country = get_my_field( 'address_country' );
     $listing_address_city = get_my_field( 'address_city' );
     $formats = array( 
        'default' => echo '<span class="my-address-country">' . $listing_address_country . '</span>';
                 echo '<span class="my-address-city">' . $listing_address_city . '</span>';
     ); 
     return $formats; 
} 
add_filter( 'default_address_formats', 'my_custom_listing_address', 15 ) ;
```

But it's still not correct. I know I'm close, but I still seem to be missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

In a php function you rather return a value and echo it after calling it and assigning its value to a variable, or echo in the function and dont return.
Dont echo inside an array, your code is full of error.

Try this:

```
function my_custom_address () {

     $listing_address_country = get_my_field( 'address_country' );
     $listing_address_city = get_my_field( 'address_city' );
     // Setting array values
    $arrayValue='<span class="my-address-country">' . $listing_address_country . 
    '</span><span class="my-address-city">' . $listing_address_city . '</span>';
     $formats = array( 
        'default' =>$arrayValue
     ); 
     return $formats; 
} 

// Now call your function
$my_custom_address=my_custom_address(); // You can use it any were
// To echo the return data do
foreach($my_custom_address as $data){
echo $data;
}
```